# I am getting swagger ui 403 error how can i fix it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, swagger, swagger-ui

This is how my microservices classes are. I have two questions.
Firstly, when I run the microservice locally, the swagger document does not open automatically. When I enter the link in the form of host/v2/api-docs with my hand, it opens as json, but the ui part does not come. I can edit and view it with the swagger editor. I added dependency to pom.xml for the UI part, but it doesn't work, how to open the UI screen?

Secondly,
Except for host/v2/api-docs, when I type a link to a controller specifically, I get a 403 authorization error. This is the most important problem that I want to overcome, how can I do it? can you help me?

link/swagger-ui.html#!/signin
localhost:8000/swagger-ui.html#!/signin

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jun 23 16:04:09 TRT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied

My pom.xml is :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
```

My SwaggerConfig class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder().deepLinking(true).validatorUrl(null).build();
    }

    private static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact("Rosaline Fox,Anna Hurt", "http://www.google.com",
            "rosaline.fox@gmail.com,anna.hurt@gmail.com");

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Auth Service Controller API Title")
                .description("Auth Service Controller API Description").version("1.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0").licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
                .contact(DEFAULT_CONTACT).build();
    }

}
```

My WebSecurityConfig class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String XI_PARTNER =  "XIPartner";
    private static final String XI_CONSULTANT =  "XIConsultant";
    private static final String SALES =  "Sales";
    private static final String STANDART =  "Standart";
    public static final String ADMIN =  "Admin";

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    private HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable CSRF (cross site request forgery)
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler((req, res, e) ->  handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(req, res, null, e));
        
        // Entry points
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/signin/otp", "/**/signin/**", "/**/v2/api-docs/**", "/**/swagger-ui.html#/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/customers/create").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/customers/update").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/customers/all").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/customers/deactivate").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/customers/reactivate").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/products/create").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/products/update").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/users/create").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/users/update").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/users/deactivate").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/users/reactivate").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/admin/user/all").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/**/xicustomers/create").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/xicustomers/update").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/xicustomers/all").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/partner/create").hasAnyAuthority(SALES)
                .antMatchers("/**/xicustomers/list").hasAnyAuthority(XI_PARTNER,XI_CONSULTANT)
                .antMatchers("/**/report/list/**").hasAnyAuthority(XI_CONSULTANT)

                .antMatchers("/**/originator").hasAnyAuthority(STANDART)
                .antMatchers("/**/blackhour/add").hasAnyAuthority(STANDART)
                .antMatchers("/**/blackhour").hasAnyAuthority(STANDART)
                .antMatchers("/**/access/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/**/pwd/forgot").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/**/maximo").anonymous()

                .anyRequest().authenticated();      

        // Apply JWT
        http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));

        // Optional, if you want to test the API from a browser
        // http.httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow eureka client to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*/")//
                .antMatchers("/eureka/**")//
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**"); // Request type options
                                                            // should be
                                                            // allowed.
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

}

My Controller Class : 

@ApiOperation(value = "Login Service", notes = "Login service with captcha verification.")
@PostMapping("/signin")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
    LoginResponse loginResponse = this.loginService.login(loginRequest);
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(loginResponse);
}



My JwtTokenFilterConfigurer class :

public class JwtTokenFilterConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {   

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    
    public JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtTokenFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(this.jwtTokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

My JwtTokenFilter class :

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    
    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        //HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        String token = getBearerToken((HttpServletRequest) req);

        if (token != null && !requestURI.contains("/signin/otp")) {
            TokenParams params = null;          
            try {
                params = this.jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token);
            } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.warn("Invalid Token: {}, Error: {}", params, e.getMessage());
                //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "INVALID JWT token");             
                //return;
                throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }

            if (!params.getRoles().contains(WebSecurityConfig.ADMIN) && params.isForOtp() == true) {
                log.warn("Invalid Token: {}, it is for OTP!", params);
                //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "INVALID JWT token");
                //return;
                throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }
            
            Authentication auth = this.jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);           
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            HeaderMapRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(request);
            wrappedRequest.addHeader("companyId", params.getCompanyId());
            wrappedRequest.addHeader("user", params.getEmail());

            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, res);

        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
    
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    
    private String getBearerToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        /*
         * if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
         * return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length()); }
         */
        if (bearerToken != null) {
            return bearerToken;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "when I type a link to a controller specifically, I get a 403 authorization error. This is the most important problem that I want to overcome, how can I do it? can you help me?"

You mean that you go to the endpoint from the browser? Of course you get 403 because you do not have an authorisation set (token header in your case). This is usually handled by the frontend application. If you want to test what an endpoint returns, you could use Postman or `curl`, set auth header and call the endpoint

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean? At the top of my Controller class, there is the @RequestMapping("/omsg") method, then there is the url of my login method (/signin). I get a 403 error when I go only with localhost:8000/omsg. 
I still don't understand what is my mistake here :(

Comment: how do you log in to your app? do you have an authorisation header set when going to "/omsg"? you could explore this in the dev tools of your browser

Comment: I have added all the controls for authorization above, other than that, don't I need to edit the code in this way not only in my browser but also in everyone? The endpoints of the methods under the main name of my Omsg controller are also separated by different names.